# C++ how to correctly free memory?

Tags: c++

```
int main(){
    int *a = new int[5];
    int *b = new int[10];
    int *c;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
        a[i] = i * i;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        b[i] = 50;
    }
    c = a;
    a = b;
    delete[]b;
    delete[]c;
    return 0;
}
```

After the execution of code above, has the memory `a` originally pointed to been freed?

If not, how to free correctly?

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

pointer `a` has to be reserved for other uses, so it is prohibited to delete a directly.

the purpose of this code is to access the memory belonging to `b` originally via `a` and free the memory a used to possess correctly.

Comment: Yes, you delete the memory of `a` through `c`.

Comment: Why don't you just delete `a` and `b` directly? It'll save you a headache.

Comment: Even this trivial example is hard to 100% verify at a glance. The general advice is of course to avoid raw pointers and use smart pointers; and if that's impossible or undesired, I'd keep the original allocated addresses stored somewhere where they will not be overwritten. Freeing only happens through those variables. One could use `vector`s of pointers for that. Consequently implemented, it would start to look a lot like smart pointers though (because you might want to have reference counting, for example).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the memory is freed. However, be very careful when changing what a pointer points to because it can easily lead to memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

It **is** freed.

Because after `c = a;`, `c` holds the memory address of `a` originally pointed to. And you have freed `c` by `delete [] c;`.

```
// Assume originally a -> 1, b -> 2

c = a;  // Now a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 1
a = b;  // Now a -> 2, b -> 2, c -> 1
```

You can free `a` or `b`, at least one of them, they point to the same memory block. You must free `c`.

Answer (score 1):

> After the execution of code above, has the memory "a" originally
>   pointed to been freed?

Yes, the memory is freed. As `c=a`, `delete [] c;` clears the memory of `a`.

However, you don't need `*c` to clear memory, just directly delete `a` and `b`

```
delete[]a;
delete[]b;
```

**UPDATE**

As you have edited your answer and now it is more clear what you are trying to achieve,i.e. access memory pointed to by `b` via `a` but before that you want to free memory pointed to by `a`. So here's what you need to do:

**1-** First free the memory pointed to by `a`

```
delete []a;
```

**2-** Now point `a` to the memory location pointed to by `b`

```
a=b;
```

Now the memory location originally pointed to by `a` is cleared and `a` now points to where `b` is pointing.

**Note:** Keep in mind that now when you have both `a` and `b` pointing to the same memory location, if you use either `delete []a` or `delete []b`, memory location pointed to by both `a` and `b` will be cleared.

Comment: is it valid to access the memory b used to point to via pointer a?

Comment: @RubySapphire it is valid as long as `b` is pointing to some memory location. You can't access the memory pointed to by `b` via pointer `a` after you have cleared the memory pointed to by `b`

Answer (score 1):

Yes it has. Pointer are normal variables that happen to contain addresses. Since a is assigned to c. Your first allocation is freed.

Answer (score 0):

Imho a lot of confusion can be avoided when you think of `delete` as **not** acting on the pointer, but on the object it points to. It is not the pointer that is deleted, but the array. Take this example, which is actually very similar to yours:

```
struct Foo { 
     int id; 
     Foo(int i) : id(i) {} 
}; 
Foo* a = new Foo(1);
Foo* b = new Foo(2);
Foo* c;
c = a;
delete c;
c = b;
delete c;
```

The only effect `delete c;` has on `c` is that we are not allowed to derefernce it afterwards, but what gets deleted is first the `Foo` object with `id 1` and then the one with `id 2`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way - you can to think about optimizations. Maybe you don't need to allocate memory here.
See this case

```
int a[5];
int b[10];

int func(int param) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
        a[i] = i * i;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        b[i] = 50;
    }
}

int main(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i){
        func(i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You don't need to allocate/free memory per iteration. But if you have multithreading, it will be a bit more complicated.

Using similar method I greatly improved the speed of calculations in the project for science.

Your code should be clear for everybody. Think about who will be after you. If the choice between readability and speed - should choose readability.